# Требует ли Auth2 в ASP.NET сертификат SSL?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, oauth, owin

Регистрация через внешние сервисы на localhost без SSL работает. Когда поставил сайт на хостинг, никакой сервис не работает. Нужно покупать SSL или скорее всего это проблема в коде?
Мой код Callback где появляется ошибка:

```
    public async Task<ActionResult> Callback(string returnUrl)
    {
        bool isNewUser = false;
        ExternalLoginInfo loginInfo = await AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
        AppUser user = await UserManager.FindAsync(loginInfo.Login);

        if (user == null)
        {
            isNewUser = true;
            user = IdentityBuilder.CreateByDefaultWithEmail(loginInfo.Email);

            var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user);

            if (!result.Succeeded)
            {
                return View("Error", result.Errors);
            }
            else
            {
                var res = await UserManager.AddLoginAsync(user.Id, loginInfo.Login);
                if (!res.Succeeded)
                {
                    return View("Error", result.Errors);
                }
            }

            await UserManager.AddToRoleAsync(user.Id, IdentityRoleBuilder.User);
        }

        var identity = await UserManager.CreateIdentityAsync(user,
            DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);

        identity.AddClaims(loginInfo.ExternalIdentity.Claims);

        AuthenticationManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties
        {
            IsPersistent = true
        }, IdentityBuilder.BuildIdentity(identity, user));

        if (isNewUser)
        {
            return Redirect(Url.Action("AdditionalInfo", "Auth"));
        }

        return Redirect(returnUrl ?? "/");
    }
```

Comment: Что значит сервис не работает? Не могли бы поподробнее? Сервисы развернули в IIS на сервере и даже в браузере не открываются?

Comment: Когда сделал деплой на сервере внешные сервисы после запрашивании даных выбивают Error

Comment: Мне не понятно, что значит `Error`, слишком уж общее определение. Добавьте данные по ошибке в вопрос

Comment: Возможно Вам на сервере нужно открыть порты. К примеру в брандмауэре создать правила для входящих и исходящих данных на порты, указанные в привязке развернутого сайта с сервисами, где нужно разрешить передачу. Ну, либо, если Вам нужен сертификат, то в привязке при создании привязки `https` нужно указать сертификат, если таковой используется в сервисах и прописан в файле конфигурации.